# Add sorting to a Nested Gridview ASP.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sorting, gridview

I have searched high and low for how to implement this on my page. I have a top level gridview which allows sorting and nested gridviews which are dynamically generated when the page compiles so 'x' number of nested gridviews which are inside dynamic html divs which can be toggled from invisible to visible at the users command. The problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to allow sorting on these nested gridviews without collapsing the divs/causing a postback.

Below shows how the master gridview (gvSalesDiv) and the nested gridview (gvTheDivisionCustomers) are generated in asp.net

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvSalesDiv" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" runat="server" GridLines="Both" OnRowDataBound="gvOrderLineDetail_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Width="100%" Height="210px" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#DADDE2"
        HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium"  Visible="true">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Toggle Detail">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("SalesDivision") %>');">

                        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("SalesDivision") %>" alt="toggle"  border="0"
                         src="/salesconsole/toggle-off.png" />
                        </a>                      

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesDivision"  HeaderText="Sales Division">

                <ItemStyle  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="CornflowerBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastDay" SortExpression="LastDay" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last 24 Hours" >


                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastWeek" SortExpression="LastWeek" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last 7 Days" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last30Days" SortExpression="Last30Days" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last 30 Days" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last3Months" SortExpression="Last3Months" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last 3 Months" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Last6Months" SortExpression="Last3Months" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last 6 Months" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastYear" SortExpression="LastYear" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Last Year" >

                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                                 <tr>
                                 <td colspan="100">     
                             <div id="div<%# Eval("SalesDivision") %>" style="display:none;position:relative;left:25px;" >

         <h3 title="<%# Eval("SalesDivision") %> Sales"><%# Eval("SalesDivision") %> Sales Breakdown</h3>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvTheDivisionCustomers" AllowSorting="true" onsorting="GridView2_Sorting" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#DADDE2"
          Width="100%" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show More Detail">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <a href="sales-customers-detail.aspx?CustomerID=<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>&CustomerName=<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>" target="_blank" style="color:Blue; text-decoration:underline"> More Details
                        </a>                      

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="ID"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Name"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last24Hours" HeaderText="Last 24 Hours" SortExpression="LastDay" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last7Days" HeaderText="Last 7 Days" SortExpression="Last7Days" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Last30Days" HeaderText="Last 30 Days" SortExpression="Last30Days" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Last3Months" HeaderText="Last 3 Months" SortExpression="Last3Months" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Last6Months" HeaderText="Last 6 Months" SortExpression="Last6Months" DataFormatString="{0:C}"  />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="LastYear" SortExpression="LastYear" HeaderText="Last Year" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />

       </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>

                               </div>    
                                 </td></tr>    
                              </ItemTemplate>

                                            </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I populate the master gridview on Page_Load and the nested gridviews are created using the OnRowDataBound method. I have a sorting method for the master gridview which works fine as well. Below is the OnSorting method for the nested gridview, which is where I am stuck...I cannot access this object

```
    protected void GridView2_Sorting(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // TO DO : Sort the nested gridview....All I can get at is the sort expressions or
    cast the sender into a gridview but even then I wouldn't know the correct SQL query to bind with unless I knew which 'div' I was in... 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically we can say, that you are looking for an ID or something wherewith you can create the query for the sorting method?
If that is correct we can find a solution.
Put a new label inside the first gridviews(gvSalesDiv) ItemTemplate like this one:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
```

And in the codebehinde you can find it in this was:

```
Label lblID = (Label)((GridView)sender).NamingContainer.FindControl("lblID");
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see how this would work, the next problem is that this causes the state of the page to be lost ie. the Div will collapse as the outer gridview is 'rebinding' when I click to sort the inner gridview. Do you have any idea how I could maintain the state of the divs?

Comment: Maybe you can try the Ajax UpdatePanel control to force the gridview to reload without a full page postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to get the parent div the gridview resides in, you can use this:

First, you need to cast the sender to a gridview, then create an html element and cast it to the gridview's parent.  Like this:

```
    Dim test As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim div As HtmlGenericControl
    div = CType(test.Parent, HtmlGenericControl)
    Dim t As String = test.ID
```

In this example, I'm casting the sender to a button but you can easily change this.  IN this example, you will need to have the div run at the server, using " runat="server"".  If you do not want to create it on the server side, you can change how you cast from a HTMLGenericControl to ContentPlaceHolder.  Let me know if this helps or you need more information.